# jQuery mobile cloned form elements not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, clone

I am cloning a form in jQuery mobile and the cloned form elements do not seem to work. IE the select lists do not change value, you cannot slide the range sliders.

I'm trying to use the following code to clone a form and increment the name and id values on each instance of the cloned form.

```
function newObservation() {
    var len = $('.observation').length;
    var titleLen = $('.observation').length + 2;
    var $html = $('.observationTemplate').clone();

    $('.observationTitle:eq(0)').text("Observation - " + titleLen);
    $html.find('[name=audit-observation-category]').eq(0).attr({name:"audit-observation-category" + len, id:"audit-observation-category" + len});
    $html.find('[name=audit-observation-notes]').eq(0).attr({name:"audit-observation-notes" + len, id:"audit-observation-notes" + len});
    $html.find('[name=audit-observation-recommendation]').eq(0).attr({name:"audit-observation-recommendation" + len, id:"audit-observation-recommendation" + len});
    $html.find('[name=audit-observation-severity]').eq(0).attr({name:"audit-observation-severity" + len, id:"audit-observation-severity" + len});
    $html.find('[name=audit-observation-person]').eq(0).attr({name:"audit-observation-person" + len, id:"audit-observation-person" + len});
    $html.find('[name=audit-observation-date]').eq(0).attr({name:"audit-observation-date" + len, id:"audit-observation-date" + len});
    return $html.html();
}
$(document).on('pageinit', function(){
    $('<div/>', {
        'class' : 'observation', html:newObservation()
    }).appendTo('#auditContainer');

    $('#auditObservationButton').click(function() {
        $('<div/>', {
            'class':'observation', html:newObservation()
            }).hide().appendTo('#auditContainer').slideDown('slow');
    });
    $('#auditForm').on('click', '.close', function(){
        $(this).parent().fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Here is a fiddle, which outlines the code but doesn't work due to jQM erros in the library itself (or so says jsfiddle) http://jsfiddle.net/FL398/

Here is an example of what Im encountering http://dirtybirddesignlab.com/FireSafe/audit.html#auditForm if you click  'Add Observation'  the form clones, increments the name and id attributes of the elements correctly but they are in accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Firebug, I recommend installing the [Firequery](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/firequery/) add-on which will show all objects created by jQuery (and jQuery Mobile) on DOM elements.

You will see that none of the JQM widgets in your cloned form have objects set, meaning that while the UI looks correct, the elements are not enhanced, so they will not work.

In JQM 1.4 you can simply call `$(your_form).enhanceWithin()` to have JQM render all elements inside your cloned form. In JQM 1.3.2 this is not available, so I guess you would have to initialize things using `trigger("create")` for example.

Another point:
It looks like you are pre-enhancing the markup (= doing JQMs work). Problem with this will be that your elements will look nice, but won't work without the "JQM treatment". This is why in 1.4 `enhanced` option is added to the first widgets, meaning you can set `data-enhanced="true"` in the source code and JQM will only create the object ("functionality") and not touch up the UI. Again for 1.3.2 this is not available. It can be hacked together, but is a lot of work to maintain, so I'd rather use 1.4 if you pre-enhance and insist on it. Otherwise try calling

```
$(document).find("form").trigger("create")
```

to see what I mean :-)

Last tip:
I ran your page through the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/check). There are still a number of issues including a handful of duplicate ids, which will also break your page on some browsers (spell IE).

Comment: ah. now I see it. You are cloning the enhanced DOM? Hmm... I suggest binding to `[pagebeforecreate](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforecreate/)`, and fetching the **unenhanced** form from the DOM. Store it in memory and use it for the "clones". When you clone, call `trigger("create")` on the form and you should be allright.

Comment: Much appreciated insight. Could/would you be willing to elaborate on fetching the unenhanced form fro the DOM, saving it and using it for the 'clones'?

Comment: I switched to 'pagebeforecreate' and it allowd the select lists to operate as  normal on the first clone, but not any subsuquent ones. Struggling wit the 'trigger("create")'

Comment: you always need to call `create` on the parent(!) of the element or element section you want to enhance. Does that help?

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you for your knowledge!

Comment: well took your advice, got it working somewhat. Now it is cloning a select with a select nested inside it. Arggghhhh...

Comment: make sure the select HTML is JQM requires it. Check their [API select](http://api.jquerymobile.com/selectmenu/)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43347/discussion-between-dirty-bird-design-and-frequent)