# jQuery clone form submit not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm having some basic html, that contains of a modal box with a `<form>`, I take that html and append it to a div next to `<body>`, everything displays correctl only that the form submit doesn't work, it doesn't work via enter or submit button.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var windowWidth = (parseInt(window.innerWidth) - 15) + 'px',
        windowHeight = $('body').css('height');

    $tk = $("#take-survey");
    var $html = $tk.css({'width': windowWidth, 'height': windowHeight}).clone();
    $tk.remove();
    $($html).appendTo(".put-me");
    $('body .put-me #take-survey').show();
});

<div id="take-survey" style="width: 1843px; height: 2120px; display: block;">
            <div class="modal">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            Dear User,<br><br>
                            Our goal is to provide the best service possible. Please take a 1 minute to complete the following customer service questionnaire. Your comments will enable us to see how we're doing overall and find out how we can improve.<br> It only takes 1 minute!
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">





                            <form name="newSurvey" action="index.php?id=25&amp;L=1&amp;tx_arxsurvey_fesurvey[action]=create&amp;tx_arxsurvey_fesurvey[controller]=Survey" method="post">
<div style="display: none">
<input type="hidden" name="tx_arxsurvey_fesurvey[__referrer][extensionName]" value="ArxSurvey">
<input type="hidden" name="tx_arxsurvey_fesurvey[__referrer][controllerName]" value="Survey">
<input type="hidden" name="tx_arxsurvey_fesurvey[__referrer][actionName]" value="new">
<input type="hidden" name="tx_arxsurvey_fesurvey[__hmac]" value="a:3:{s:9:&quot;newSurvey&quot;;a:4:{s:6:&quot;whyUse&quot;;i:1;s:13:&quot;otherServices&quot;;i:1;s:11:&quot;suggestions&quot;;i:1;s:8:&quot;tellMore&quot;;i:1;}s:6:&quot;action&quot;;i:1;s:10:&quot;controller&quot;;i:1;}77fcb50f86112b3acd1aa7f6eff2b4adeac7a664">
</div>

                                <label for="userProfile">
    What is your user profile? <span class="required">(required)</span>
</label>
    <select name="tx_arxsurvey_fesurvey[newSurvey][userProfile]">
        <option value="Real Estate Agency">Real Estate Agency</option>
        <option value="Real Estate Marketing">Real Estate Marketing</option>
        <option value="Floor Drawing Services">Floor Drawing Services</option>
        <option value="Project Developers">Project Developers</option>
        <option value="Property Management">Property Management</option>
        <option value="Interior Design">Interior Design</option>
        <option value="Architect">Architect</option>
        <option value="Private User">Private User</option>
        <option value="Furniture Retailer">Furniture Retailer</option>
    </select>
    <label>If other please specify:</label>
    <input type="text" name="tx_arxsurvey_fesurvey[newSurvey][userProfileOther]">
<label for="useStatus">
    How often you use PlanningWiz? <span class="required">(required)</span>
</label>
<div class="hold-radios">
    <input type="radio" id="dailyUse" name="tx_arxsurvey_fesurvey[newSurvey][useStatus]" value="Daily">
    <label for="dailyUse">Daily</label>
    <input type="radio" id="weeklyUse" name="tx_arxsurvey_fesurvey[newSurvey][useStatus]" value="Weekly">
    <label for="weeklyUse">Weekly</label>
    <input type="radio" id="monthlyUse" name="tx_arxsurvey_fesurvey[newSurvey][useStatus]" value="Monthly">
    <label for="monthlyUse">Monthly</label>
    <input type="radio" id="rarelyUse" name="tx_arxsurvey_fesurvey[newSurvey][useStatus]" value="Rarely">
    <label for="rarelyUse">Rarely</label>
</div>

<label for="whyUse">
    Why are you using a room planner? <span class="required">(required)</span>
</label>
    <textarea rows="15" cols="40" name="tx_arxsurvey_fesurvey[newSurvey][whyUse]"></textarea>
<label for="otherServices">
    Are you using other room planning services as well? If so, why?  <span class="required">(required)</span>
</label>
    <textarea rows="15" cols="40" name="tx_arxsurvey_fesurvey[newSurvey][otherServices]"></textarea>
<label for="suggestions">
    What suggestions for improvement would you have? <span class="required">(required)</span>
</label>
    <textarea rows="15" cols="40" name="tx_arxsurvey_fesurvey[newSurvey][suggestions]"></textarea>
<label for="tellMore">
    I'd also like to tell you that: <span class="required">(required)</span>
</label>
    <textarea rows="15" cols="40" name="tx_arxsurvey_fesurvey[newSurvey][tellMore]"></textarea>

                        </form></div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                <input class="save" type="submit" name="" value="Create new">
                                <input type="button" value="Skip for now!" class="skip">

                        </div>
                    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
                </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
            </div><!-- /.modal -->
        </div>
```

Comment: done Sir! updated the main post

Comment: What exactly do you mean by not working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Submit` button not inside the form so close the `</form>` tag after the submit button

```
   <div class="modal-footer">
             <input class="save" type="submit" name="" value="Create new">
             <input type="button" value="Skip for now!" class="skip">

      </div>
   </form> // add form close here
```

Comment: That's really strange because it is in the template files, but on clone...it doesn't copy the </form> close tag

Comment: You can copy your html code and put it on fiddle click submit button nothing happen,but after adding close tag after submit button the form submit

Answer (score 0):

You need to reinitialize the form. Just like this:

```
    $(document).find("form").trigger("create")
```

"In JQM 1.4 you can simply call $(your_form).enhanceWithin() to have JQM render all elements inside your cloned form. In JQM 1.3.2 this is not available, so I guess you would have to initialize things using trigger("create") for example."

There are a same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20617624/jquery-mobile-cloned-form-elements-not-working)