# Cloning div and incrementing

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am atempting to clone a div (multiple times) and add increments so I can parse the results into a database using XML. I only want to clone the form section not the data entered. The Div I am cloning has 3 selects and 2 radios (all of which when added need to be empty).

HTML

```
<div id="Template1" class="template">
    <div class="_100">
              <div class="_25"> <fieldset>   
<label class="label_analysis" for="analysis">Analyte:</label>
        <select class="select_analyte" name="analysis" id="analysis">
        <option value="">Select</option>
               <option value="TN">TN</option>
               <option value="TP,NO2+3">TP,NO2+3</option>
               </select>  </fieldset></div>
              <div data-role="controlgroup" class="_13">
          <label><input type="checkbox" data-mini="true" name="Filtered" id="Filtered" value="True">
              0.45u Filtered</label>
              <label><input type="checkbox" data-mini="true" name="Dup" id="Dup" value="True">
              Field Dup</label></div>

      <div class="_25"><fieldset>
          <label class="label_preserve" for="preserve">Preserved</label>
        <select class="select_preserve" name="preserve" id="preserve">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="HNO3">HNO&#8323;</option>
            <option value="H2SO4">H&#8322;SO&#8324;</option>
         </select></fieldset></div> 
    <div class="_20"> <fieldset> 
   <label class="label_cool" for="cool">Cooled</label>
        <select class="select_cool" name="cool" id="cool">  
            <option value="">Select</option>
               <option value="Ice">Ice</option>
               <option value="Frozen">Frozen</option>
               <option value="None">None</option>
            </select>
        </fieldset></div>

    <div class="_13">
        <a href="#" type="button" data-theme="e" data-mini="true" data-icon="add" title="Duplicate" class="showNew">Add Analyte</a>
        <a href="#" type="button" data-theme="e" data-mini="true" data-icon="delete" title="Remove" class="removeNew">Remove</a></div>
       </div>
    </div>
           <div id="place" class="place"></div>
```

I have tried two different scripts

This script works as I want to hide the remove button on the original div and only have it appear on the cloned but it doesn't increment.

```
     (function($){
    var Template = $('.Template');
    var count = 0;
    $('.removeNew').hide().on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('.Template').remove();
    });
    $('a.showNew').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var clone = Template.clone(true, true).insertAfter("#place").find('.removeNew').show().end();

    });
})(jQuery);
```

and this one which increments but doesn't hide the remove button

```
      $('#showNew').click(function() {
      var num = $('.template').length,
      newNum = new Number(num + 1),
      newElem = $('#Template' + num).clone(true, true).attr('id', 'Template' + newNum).appendTo('#place');
      newElem.find('.analysis').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_analysis').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_analysis').val();
      newElem.find('.preserve').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_preserve').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_preserve').val();
      newElem.find('.cool').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_cool').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_cool').val();
    $('#Template'+ num).after(newElem);
   });
 })
```

I am wondering if there is some way to combine them...

I am also having issues as no matter what I seem to try the original div becomes the clone, complete with remove button, while what should be the original div can be changed.

Comment: I highly recommend that you clean up your code with consistent tabbing, etc, so that it is clearer what is going on.  It also would be a good idea to make a jsfiddle so that others can edit your code.

Comment: I got you [started](http://jsfiddle.net/FLdTL/1/) but you will have to clean it up yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the simplest approach is to have an original copy of the template hidden and base all clones off of that. This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u2ymk/1/) demonstrates this approach.

```
(function ($) {
    var Template = $('#Template');
    var count = 0;
    var nextId = 0;

    Template.find('.removeNew').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('.template').remove();
        count--;
    });

    function cloneTemplate(removable) {
        var clone = Template.clone(true, true);
        clone.attr('id', clone.attr('id') + nextId);

        clone.find('label[for]').each(function( index ) {
            var elem = $(this);
            elem.attr('for', elem.attr('for') + nextId);
        });

        clone.find('select, input').each(function( index ) {
            var elem = $(this);
            elem.attr('id', elem.attr('id') + nextId);
            elem.attr('name', elem.attr('name') + nextId);
        });

        if (!removable) {
            clone.find('.removeNew').remove();
        }

        clone.insertBefore("#addNew").removeClass('hide');
        count++;
        nextId++;
    }

    // Create First Analyte and delete the remove button.
    cloneTemplate(false);

    $('a.showNew').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        cloneTemplate(true);
        return false;
    });
})(jQuery);
```

It didn't make sense to have the `Add New` button inside the template so I moved it outside. All new clones are added before the `Add New` button.

You should notice in the script above that the first element is created by cloning the `Template`. Then new elements are created calling the same `clone` function when the `Add New` button is clicked.

<strike>Note: This solution does not include updating element `id` or `name` attributes. Something that you almost certainly want to do.</strike>

Comment: Thank you! it works well (perfectly on JSFiddle) except, as I have been battling all month, everything seems to be backwards when on my form. There must be some type of conflict in my code that is messing with my head. I have posted my form here http://deq.mt.gov/wqinfo/WQlibrary/SiteVisit/index.html#chapter2 , I know it's asking a lot but would you mind looking at it and trying to figure out where my problem is. the sam type of issue is occuring on the Benthic Chl-a samples tab.

Comment: It appears the problem has a lot to do with using jquery mobile. The jquery mobile enhancements to the dom are cloned along with the elements which is causing the problem. This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20617624/jquery-mobile-cloned-form-elements-not-working) may help.

Comment: I appreciate the fixes. With the new script the first iteration of the Div allows me to enter data and add a new div but the new div cannot be changed. I think I hate Jquery Mobile.